# How many seats of each political party are up for grabs in 2018 for the house of reps?

Tags: united-states, election, congress

I was able to find the split for the senate, but the Wikipedia article doesn't tell me about the split for the house. Is there a source I can use to find this?

Comment: All of them....

Comment: What is your criteria for "up for grabs"?

Comment: Now I get it, I didn't realize the term limit was 2 years. (I thought the elections were staggered like the senate) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2018 is a mid-term election as it happens in between 2 presidential elections.

Below, sums-up what mid-term congressional elections are held:

**House Elections:**

- All 435 seats hold elections.

**Senate Elections:**

- 1/3 of Senate seats will hold elections
- Around 33/34 seats will be "up for grabs"

**Gubernatorial Elections:**

- 34 of the 50 U.S. states will elect their governors to four-year terms during midterm elections
- Vermont and New Hampshire elect governors to two-year terms in both midterm and presidential elections
- So, there will be Gubernatorial Elections in 36 states during mid-term elections.